# SwiftUI, Firestore getting one collection and matching with another

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am so confused with linking one collection to another, any feedback would be appreciated.
I have to collections I coded them as structs:

```
struct KetoTarif:  Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct Keto:  Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    
    var id: Int
    var breakfast: String //this should match with name in KetoTarif
}
```

And I fetch my data for the Keto as follows:

```
class KetoViewModel:  ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var ketoDays = [Keto]()
    func fetchData() {
        
        db.collection("keto").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            self.ketoDays = documents.compactMap { document in
                do {
                    let x = try document.data(as: Keto.self)
                    return x
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly I do the same thing for my second collection

```
class KetoTarifViewModel:  ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var ketoTarifler = [KetoTarif]()
    func fetchData() {
        
        db.collection("ketotarifler").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            self.ketoTarifler = documents.compactMap { document in
                do {
                    let x = try document.data(as: KetoTarif.self)
                    return x
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally my view I added my main aim as a comment:

```
struct KetoDiyet: View {
    @ObservedObject var ketoModel = KetoViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var ketoTarifModel = KetoTarifViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            Text("c")
            
            ForEach(ketoModel.ketoDays) { keto in
                //here keto.breakfast returns a string
                // and I want to search/find/print that string in ketoTarifModel
                
            }
            
            }.onAppear() {
                self.ketoModel.fetchData()
                self.ketoTarifModel.fetchData()
             
                
            }
    }
}
```

Main idea is Keto has a string (breakfast) which should match with name in KetoTarif.
I just switched from Relational Database and having an issue putting my mind on this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me thank you for the nice question. All code provided, clear question. Loving it!

Then, you got two possibilities that kind of depend on the use case. Are there multiple matches or just one? Anyhow. The code below should do and is compiling in Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var ketoModel = KetoViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var ketoTarifModel = KetoTarifViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            Text("c")
            
            ForEach(ketoModel.ketoDays) { keto in
                
                // get the first element that satisfies your needs
                if let firstKetoTarifModel = ketoTarifModel.ketoTarifler.first(where: {$0.name == keto.breakfast}) {
                    Text(firstKetoTarifModel.name)
                }
                
                // get multiple elements
                ForEach(ketoTarifModel.ketoTarifler) { ketoTarifler in
                    if ketoTarifler.name == keto.breakfast {
                        Text(ketoTarifler.name)
                    }
                }
                
                //here keto.breakfast returns a string
                // and I want to search/find/print that string in ketoTarifModel
                
            }
            
            }.onAppear() {
                self.ketoModel.fetchData()
                self.ketoTarifModel.fetchData()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: For loop in for loop might be a pain with large datasets.

Comment: I was going onto very wrong directions. Thank you so much for your answer!